# problem with setting up a two side document

Tags: double-sided, page, layout

I do have the following problem: I wrote my theorem, and in the end I wanted to change it to `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}`
instead of `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}`.
But when I made these change the format of my document is changed, in some phage a random unexpectedly big space area are added, and the itemze spacer are increased but only in a few page, the other pages stay the decent look.

Can anybody help me what could I make wrong ?

Comment: I assume that twoside also changes the geometry settings of your pages. Try using the `geometry` package in order to set the page layout to your needs...

Comment: `twoside` defaults to `\flushbottom` so you may prefer `\raggedbottom` (as used for `oneside`)

Answer (score 1):

Running the following document with `oneside` shows in the logfile (at the end)
the following setting:

```
\textwidth=418.25368pt
\textheight=591.5302pt
```

These values can be used for twoside to get the same layout, except that `oneside` uses `\raggedbottom`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=418.25368pt,textheight=591.5302pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and how can I chech that oneside is using \raggedbottom ?

Comment: That is the default setting for report. And can be seen in the output.